# Angular OR condition issue throwing an error

Tags: angularjs

`Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$parse/syntax?p0=or&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=34&p3=group.title%20!%3D%20'Local'"<!-- ngIf: group.title != 'Local' or group.title != 'Server' -->"r%20group.title%20!%3D%20'Server%20News'&p4=or%20group.title%20!%3D%20'Server%20News'`

```
<li ng-if="edit === false && filtered.length === 0">
    <p ng-if="group.title != 'Local' or group.title != 'Server'" style="padding: 5px;">No links in group.</p>

</li>
```

1. I have have  " || "  instead of  " or "  and that is NOT working

Comment: Logic like this should be pushed into your controller, ideally you would want `ng-if="ctrl.shouldShowWarning()"` or similar. It will also help you debug it easier as you can breakpoint that method and see if something is undefined, etc. The `||` operator is all you _should_ need.

Comment: True,  I inherited this application which is angular/node.js   and every controller, directive is built in non-stardard way  ( nothing i see on pluralsight.com ,  online examples etc..  ,  so the previous guy made it just different to understand what I already am not understanding   -  i agree with you  as with asp.net mvc   that is how i would handle it   thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression will always be true, since group.title cannot be 'Local' and 'Server' together.

```
group.title != 'Local' || group.title != 'Server'
```

In other words, if group.title = 'Local', you have

```
false || true = true
```

If group.title = 'Server', you have

```
true || false = true
```

If group.title = 'somethingElse', you have

```
true || true = true
```

I guess you want to do the following:

```
group.title != 'Local' && group.title != 'Server'  // note the && instead of ||
```

which would mean: Show "No links in group." if group.title is not 'Local' and is also not 'Server'

Comment: Yes,  that works,  for some reason I was thinking that would not work based on the page specific routing ...   cool  thx